# Problem express with nginx reverse proxy, not send static file

Tags: express, nginx, proxy

Nginx when I ask for my static file always returns 404, but with I understand what the reason is, if I'm wrong something that surely is so you can explain to me why it was wrong:
here are the configuration files:

**default.conf**

```
upstream apps {
  server webapi:9000 fail_timeout=10s max_fails=5;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

    location @apphost {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass http://apps;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following two articles helped me:

[.Net Core 3.0 Nginx not serving static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194114/net-core-3-0-nginx-not-serving-static-files)

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/

I added following two blocks under my server block:

```
  location /assets/ {
     }

  location ~ \.(css|js|lib|png) {
        root /var/apps/dev/myapp/wwwroot;
    }
```